# Can I add custom links to the visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce-template

I have 2 custom links on my orders object and I am trying to put it on my Visualforce Email Template but when i try to save, it says 
Error: Invalid field Search_PO_Contact_Name for SObject VM_Sales_Order__c. The code i wrote is as follows

Search PO Contact Name: {!relatedTo.Search_PO_Contact_Name}

Search PO Contact Name: {!relatedTo.Search_Lab_Name}

is there a way i can get them on my visualforce page

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to suffix your fields with `__c`!